# What is the difference between manifest file and xml file in android

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I am new to android.I want to know what is the main difference between android Manifest file and android XML file.Both are written in the same xml. But,What is the main difference between them can any one tell me with explanation please.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/AndroidManifest.html) about the manifest

It says

> The manifest file presents essential information about your app to the
>   Android system, information the system must have before it can run any
>   of the app's code.

The file type of this manifest file should be `.xml`

And, regarding other XML files, almost all of the other data, apart from the code, everything is specified in an XML format.

according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), the reason why XML is used is as follows

> The advantage to declaring your UI in XML is that it enables you to
>   better separate the presentation of your application from the code
>   that controls its behavior. Your UI descriptions are external to your
>   application code, which means that you can modify or adapt it without
>   having to modify your source code and recompile. For example, you can
>   create XML layouts for different screen orientations, different device
>   screen sizes, and different languages. Additionally, declaring the
>   layout in XML makes it easier to visualize the structure of your UI,
>   so it's easier to debug problems. As such, this document focuses on
>   teaching you how to declare your layout in XML. If you're interested
>   in instantiating View objects at runtime, refer to the ViewGroup and
>   View class references.